# Why does handler.postDelayed stop running when app is backgrounded but rxjava2's Observable.interval does not?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I am interested in why two methods which are both running on the main thread appear to survive activity death in very different ways. Does anyone have any insight why rxjava's `Observable.Interval` continues to run, while `handler.postDelayed` does not?

I have an activity which is subscribing to a class, `DataStore`. The class emits updates every 1s. The 1s is controlled by some sort of poll (either `handler.postDelayed` or `Observable.Interval`)

When the activity is backgrounded, it is killed by the OS after a short time but the `DataStore` class not killed. A service is able to query it for updates but the poll no longer functions when it is written with `handler.postDelayed`.

In order to obtain the handler I am using, I am just calling `Handler()`

Comment: Which interval overload? The default runs on an RxJava thread.

Comment: @akarnokd I tried running it on rxjava's default thread and on the main thread and it performed the same.

Comment: What RxAndroid version are you using?

Comment: @akarnokd `2.0.1`

Comment: "When the activity is backgrounded, it is killed by the OS after a short time"  - if OS wants to kill you, it will kill your all process, not a component